# AWS Cognito Developer Authentication in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Am trying to implement developer authentication using the PHP SDK but keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Aws\CognitoIdentity\Exception\CognitoIdentityException: AWS Error
>   Code: AccessDeniedException, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID:
>   da162f98-fb50-11e4-937e-0bf2642a4752, AWS Error Type: client, AWS
>   Error Message: User: arn:aws:iam::256661818246:user/tester is not
>   authorized to perform:
>   cognito-identity:GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity on resource:
>   arn:aws:cognito-identity:us-east-1:256661818246:identitypool/us-east-1:69767873-2de2-4cc7-a78f-3d18b5e9bf71,
>   User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.8.3 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.20.0 PHP/5.3.6
>   thrown in
>   /var/www/html/aws/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php
>   on line 91

This is my sample code:

```
<?php
session_start();

//Include AWS client libs
require (dirname(__DIR__).'/aws/aws-autoloader.php');
use Aws\CognitoIdentity\CognitoIdentityClient;
use Aws\Sts\StsClient;

/* Global Vars */
$aws_region = 'us-east-1';
$aws_key = '<AWS_KEY>';
$aws_secret = '<AWS_SECRET>';
$aws_account_id = '<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>';
$identity_pool_id = 'us-east-1:xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx';

//Initialize a Cognito Identity Client using the Factory
$client = CognitoIdentityClient::factory(array('region' => $aws_region, 'key' => $aws_key, 'secret' => $aws_secret));

/* Acquire new Identity */
$identity = $client->getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(array('IdentityPoolId' => $identity_pool_id, 'Logins' => array('login.custom.traffic' => 'jkljkasdjk')));

//Obtain Identity from response data structure
$id = $identity->get('IdentityId');
echo "IdentityId: ".$id;
?>
```

I suspect the error occurs while trying to get the developer Identity. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason behind this error is there might be no policy attached to the IAM user 'tester'.
You can attach an already existing policy 'AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities' from IAM console which gives this user access to Cognito APIs including 'getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity' as well.

Comment: Thanks Vinay. I had spent a lot of time scouring through Cognito's identity pool instead of IAM as you have rightfully mentioned.